# Customize font python matplotlib - use 2 fonts in the same graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I would like to use two different fonts in the same graph, for instance I would like the x-axis label written in `Font1` and the y-axis one in `Font2`. It seems that the setting of the second font is simply ignored (see the code reported below) and all texts are generated in `Font1`.

```
from matplotlib import rcParams

rcParams['font.family'] = 'Font1'
plt.title('Test 1')
plt.xlabel('Axis x ')
rcParams['font.family'] = 'Font2'
plt.ylabel('Axis y ')
```

Is it possible to manage two fonts in the same plot?

Comment: Just pass the font to the text generating calls  [`set_title`][1], [`set_xlabel`][2] and [`set_ylabel`][3]


  [1]: http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title
  [2]: http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlabel
  [3]: http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylabel